# Yii2: update and delete field with query builder

Tags: sql, mysql, yii2

How can I update field with query builder in Yii2? How to translate UPDATE, DELETE function to yii2?

Thanks!

```
UPDATE u4_portal.missed SET type='vacations' WHERE reason LIKE BINARY 'отпуск%';
DELETE FROM u4_portal.missed  where type = 'vacations';
UPDATE u4_portal.missed SET type='absents';
```

I tried this:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE u4_portal.missed SET type='vacations' WHERE reason LIKE BINARY 'отпуск%';
DELETE FROM u4_portal.missed  where type = 'vacations';
UPDATE u4_portal.missed SET type='absents'")
->execute();
```

It didn't work out

Comment: Have you tried using three different query execution?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Didn't work either
Or: 
`$query->createCommand()->update('missed', ['type' => 'vacations'], ['like', 'reason', 'отпуск%'])->execute();
`

Comment: `$query->createCommand()->update('missed', ['type' => 'vacations'], ['like', 'reason', 'отпуск%'])->sql`, get generated sql query and analize query. is sql correctly generated? you can execute that sql on phpmyadmin